# How can I dump every single champion sounds in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

How can I either dump from the game install, or download somewhere, all of the league of legends champion sounds?

I would like a method that gets the latest champion sounds since new champions come out often!

Thank you kindly!

EDIT:
I found all the sounds I want on the wiki page here but I am hoping there is a way to download them all at once:

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Champion_audio

Answer (score 2):

What's up man, I can help you out here.  The sound files are a little complicated, don't go download them, as it's just gonna be a large download and I can't find a place where you can find them ALL.
The place you can find them is the Riot Games folder **on your HDD**.  There is gonna be one main place you can find them.  You will have to download a couple programs to be able to play them.  You also may have to find some audio converter files online to get the files in the format you want them to be.

Here it is, now this is gonna be where all the sounds are, I'm pretty sure anyway

- `C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\projects\lol_game_client_en_us\managedfiles`

Programs Needed:

- [fsbext](https://github.com/gdawg/fsbext)
- [MusicPlayerEx](http://jerome.jouvie.free.fr/Fmod/Projects/Project1.php)

Hope this helped, let me know if this doesn't include all the files you need, and I'll do some more digging later and edit this answer.

**ALSO BE AWARE** there are MANY fake conversion files out there, there is a high risk of getting a virus.   Just be careful when you are searching for those.  Don't just hit the first 'download' button you see.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I don't have an "air' or "game" folder in "C:\Riot Games\League of Legends" tho...

Comment: @SuperR Well then you installed it somewhere else. There must be an installation directory somewhere. Maybe its `C:\Program Files (x86)\Riot Games`

Comment: @YUNOWORK yeah mine is outside of my Program Files (x86), not sure why.

Comment: @SuperR Lemme check on that

Comment: @TrapHappy mine is in the same place that yours is but I do ntoh ave those directories

Comment: @SuperR I edited the first accordingly, the second will come soon, just gotta dig a bit, didn't realize how much Rito's files have changed over the years

Comment: @SuperR So the files are totally different, not sure if the programs are correct anymore, but I do know that a ton of the sound files are in the place I just edited into my answer.